# Calculus 2: Integral with Trig Cosine Double Angle $\int_{\frac\pi{12}}^{\frac\pi2}(1-\cos4x)\cos2xdx$

Tags: calculus

I'm stuck on the following problem:

$$\int_{\frac\pi{12}}^{\frac\pi2}(1-\cos4x)\cos2x\>dx$$

I think I can use the double angle formulas here but I'm not sure how to apply it, or even if it's the right approach.  I'm also not sure if 1-cos4x can be translated into anything.

[image]

A step-through would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the double angle identity to write $1-\cos 4x = 2\sin^2 2x$,

$$\int_{\frac\pi{12}}^{\frac\pi2}(1-\cos4x)\cos2xdx
=\int_{\frac\pi{12}}^{\frac{\pi}2}\sin^2 2x\>d(\sin 2x)= \frac13 \sin^32x\bigg|_ {\frac\pi{12}}^{\frac{\pi}2}=-\frac1{24}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

For this type of integrals, use the linearisation formulæ:
$$2\sin a\sin b=\cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b),\qquad2\cos a\cos b=\cos(a-b)+\cos(a+b),$$
$$2\sin a\cos b=\sin(a-b)+\sin(a+b.$$

*Some details*:

\begin{align}
\int_{\frac\pi{12}}^{\frac\pi2}(1-\cos4x)\cos2x\,\mathrm dx&=\int_{\frac\pi{12}}^{\frac\pi2}(\cos 2x-\cos4x\cos2x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_{\frac\pi{12}}^{\frac\pi2}\bigl(\cos 2x-\frac12(\cos2x-\cos6x)\bigr)\,\mathrm dx \\
&= \frac12\int_{\frac\pi{12}}^{\frac\pi2}\bigl(\cos 2x+\cos6x)\,\mathrm dx = \frac14\sin 2x+\frac1{12}\sin 6x\,\Biggr|_{\frac\pi{12}}^{\frac\pi2}
\end{align}

Comment: I'm sorry but this hint is not enough; I don't know how to map that linearisation formula to my particular problem

Comment: Expand the integrand by distributivity. One of the terms obtained corresponds to one of the formulæ.